# Mixing less and sass files in angular application

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less, ng-zorro-antd

I'm building an Angular application using the ng-zorro library for components. Usually, I also import the entire Bootstrap css file for some utilities like grid system and spacing classes which I have found very useful. In all my previous experiences I have had problems with conflicts generated by ng-zorro css and boostrap css so, for this project, I would like to import only the Boostrap css classes I need.

By reading the official documentation I learned how to import specific packages from Bootstrap with SCSS (e.g. `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";` ).

Therefore, I have a .less file with the ng-zorro custom theme for the components and a .scss file with the Bootstrap-specific utility classes. The problem is that the Bootstrap scss file appears to not actually be seen by the components.

It might be helpful to know that I set up the project with Angular CLI and when asked what css file I wanted for the project, I chose less. The reason for my choice was that the ng-zorro costume themes must be written with .less and I want to know if there is a way to tell the Angular compiler to use both .less and .scss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it really matters what styling sub-language you use, you just need to avoid coding it inside a CSS file, you have two options where it works.

- In the angular.json, `styles` array, angular will parse both `less` and `scss`
- In the styles array of `@Component` decorator, angular will parse both `less` and `scss`

Below is a stackblitz with angular parsing multiple css types

```
 ...
 "options": {
            "assets": [],
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "outputPath": "dist/demo",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/global_styles.css",
              "src/global_styles.scss",
              "src/global_styles.less"
            ],
            ...
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hfu7id?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=angular.json,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

---

Additionally please have a look at this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli#sass-include-paths) Where it explains that you can include the files of `scss` and `less` inside the `stylePreprocessorOptions.includePaths` where it will get read fine

```
"styles": [
  "styles.scss"
],
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss"
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I looked the stackblitz you provided and I am facing the the same problem I have in my project: boostrap classes are not loaded... The last button is not styled with the bootstrap classes btn btn-primary.

Comment: @GianmarcoSanti Could you modify the stackblitz and share the replicated scenario, else provide the github repo to check!

Comment: in the end I found out that there was two problems. The first one has been resolved thanks to your solution adding "StylePreprocessorOptions". The second one was related to the naming of the imported files of bootstrap which apparently has to be written including the extension. Thank you very much for the support!

Comment: @GianmarcoSanti you're welcome! Glad it's fixed!